# How do i change the void limit on roblox for players die ? (roblox studio)

Tags: lua, settings, roblox

How i can change the void limit of Roblox for anyone or part is under 2000 and not 500 by default dont die ? I want to make a adminbase base at Y = -1466.704 and not lower or more i can just this because i have the map above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    --workspace.FallenPartsDestroyHeight=-1500
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the line?